# How to paginate data from child object in EF?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I have a problem.

I want to paginate `ClassA`.

`ClassA` has a list of elements of type `ClassB`, and `ClassB` has a list of element of type `ClassC`.

**How can I paginate data by the number of elements from `ClassC`?**

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassBCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ICollection<ClassA> ClassACollection { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ClassC> ClassCCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC
{
    public ICollection<ClassB> ClassBCollection { get; set; }
}
```

**ClassA**  | **ClassB**     | **ClassC** 
Data1  | InnerData | InnerInnerData1 
          |                   | InnerInnerData2 
          |                   | InnerInnerData3 
          |                   | InnerInnerData4 
          |                   | InnerInnerData5 (Paginate here)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your code alright? There is a collection of class C in class B. Also there is a collection of class B in class C which is a never ending circle?

Comment: Yes. It's correctly, the EF resolved many to many relationships this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can resolve with System.Linq.Queryable
The solution like this:

```
var result =  from A in DataContext<A>()
              .Include(x => x.B)
              .Include(x => x.B.C)
              .Orderby(x => x.C)
              .ThenBy(x => x.B)
              .ThenBy(x => x.A)
              .Skip(pageNumber * pageSize)
              .Take(pageSize);
```

That's all Folks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method in class B GetPageRange()

```
    public ICollection<ClassC> GetPageRange(int startingPage, int pagesPerPage)
    {
        return (from c in ClassCCollection
                select c).Skip(startingPage).Take(pagesPerPage).ToList();
    }
```